# Chrome and Firefox cannot add specific URL to home screen

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser, home-screen-shortcuts, firefox-for-android, hyperlinks

I'm using Chrome and Firefox on Android 10. I need to add a link to my home screen and I can't find a way to add the specific link.

I know that I can do the following:

1. Go to the URL
2. Tap the overflow (3-dot) menu
3. Add to home screen

However, if I navigate to a specific URL **within** some sites, like Weather Underground (https://www.wunderground.com/) and follow the above process, it doesn't add the specific URL, it adds `www.wunderground.com` and doesn't seem to give me any way to edit that URL to reference the specific subpage (e.g. `www.wunderground.com/my/specific/url`).

Why, and how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to use a special app like [Shortcut To URL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.miotti.ShortcutToURL) to create the shortcut?

Comment: I am still having this issue despite @beeshyams fix. Attaching [Wikipedia - Mithridatism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mithridatism) to my home screen instead creates a link to the [home page of the mobile Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org).
Meanwhile, I've found forcing the desktop view of the page, then attaching to home screen works, linking to the correct desktop subpage. (Chrome `83.0.4103.106` on Android 10 on a Nokia 7.2 device)

Comment: @D-zap I requested Andrew (who posted answer) to check my solution and he reverted that it didn't work for him too. Hence, deleted my answer// Why it worked for me is still a mystery but that's another question

Answer (score 7):

#### tl;dr

Using the browsers' "Add to Home Screen" (A2HS) feature may not open the expected link due to the browsers trying to comply with the standard of Progressive Web Application (PWA). Try other approaches instead, like **using app widgets or 3rd-party apps altogether (examples below)**.

#### Progressive Web Application (PWA), Manifest file, and Add to Home Screen (A2HS)

To put it simply, [PWA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps) is an advanced web app that follows some rules. One of them is having a manifest file.

> In order to call a Web App a PWA, technically speaking it should have the following features: Secure contexts (**HTTPS**), one or more Service Workers, and a [manifest file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest).

[A2HS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Add_to_home_screen#How_do_you_make_an_app_A2HS-ready) is a browser feature to "install" a web app based on the configuration in the manifest file, which is [linked on the header tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest#Deploying_a_manifest_with_the_link_tag).

```
<head>
   ...
   <link rel="manifest" href="link_to_manifest_file">
   ...
</head>
```

One of the required fields in the manifest file is [`start_url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/start_url) that will be loaded when opening the "app".

> The `start_url` member is a string that represents the start URL of the web application — the prefered URL that should be loaded when the user launches the web application (e.g., when the user taps on the web application's icon from a device's application menu or homescreen).

[If `start_url` is invalid](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#start_url-member), it *may* return the document URL instead (i.e. the exact URL when the page is added to the home screen). However, since the manifest file is configured by the web developer, it might be difficult for end-users to modify/override this value.

In short, when a user adds a web page to the home screen, the browser will check if there is a manifest file, and if there is, it will try to use its value.

#### Some examples...

- Wikimedia (including Wikipedia, Gamepedia, and possibly other wikis) has a mobile front-end extension that will *only* add the manifest file to the mobile view [with `start_url` always pointing to the Main Page](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-MobileFrontend/blob/master/includes/api/ApiWebappManifest.php#L25).

  The manifest file:
  `<link rel="manifest" href="/w/api.php?action=webapp-manifest">`

  The content of the manifest file:

  ```
  {"name":"Wikipedia","orientation":"portrait","dir":"ltr","lang":"en","display":"browser","theme_color":"#eaecf0","background_color":"#fff","start_url":"/wiki/Main_Page","icons":[{"src":"/static/apple-touch/wikipedia.png","sizes":"160x160","type":"image/png"}]}
  ```

  This is why adding the desktop version works (and depending on the browser's configuration, it will redirect to the mobile view automatically), but adding the mobile view always returns to the Main Page instead.
- Weather Underground always sets the manifest file regardless if it is viewed on desktop or mobile.

  The manifest file:
  `<link rel="manifest" href="bundle-next/manifest.webmanifest">`

  Containing `"start_url": "/",` which is basically the domain itself.

#### Solutions and/or workarounds

- Some sites only have a manifest file on mobile view, using desktop mode may mitigate this issue
- Some [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) apps may allow opening an exact URL. Tasker has "Browse URL" task and users can also add an app widget on the home screen as a shortcut to that task
- Some 3rd-party apps can [create a home screen shortcut to a URL](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=url%20shortcut%20home%20screen&c=apps)
- Changing user agent *may* work (e.g. by using XPrivacyLua as mentioned by user [beeshyams](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/131553/beeshyams) in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54868660#54868660)). According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/start_url),

  > **Note:** The `start_url` member is purely advisory, and a user agent may ignore it or allow the user to alter it at install time or afterwards.
- (Idea, untested) strip the `<link rel="manifest" href="link_to_manifest_file">` tag (e.g. using "ad" blockers) from the HTML when the page is loaded.

Comment: Is this behavior intentional on the part of the website, or is this badly implemented PWA standards?

Comment: @D-zap It's hard to answer that without knowing the web devs' intent. On one hand, `start_url` is actually optional for PWA; emptying it will just return the document URL instead. On the other hand, AH2S seems requiring it.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that works for me:

1. shorten the link with some website like Bitly com
2. turn off the internet access
3. paste a shoterned link to your browser and try to reach it
4. unavailable internet will give you a time to add this "proxy" page to your home screen

Now I have a link, not an in-browser application.

Comment: I found that I didn't have to use a link shortener. My use case was going to www.nhl.com/kraken/schedule that would redirect to a particular day's URL. I set my phone on airplane mode, went to the url, then added it to home screen and that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the link from @Andrew T, this well-reviewed Android app seems perfect for linking to any website (or even Action within an Android app):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rk.android.app.shortcutmaker

Just tried it and it did exactly what I wanted with no fuss and some nice options.