# How to add website as a website link with Brave/Chrome to the Android home screen?

Tags: chrome-for-android

On a Chrome or other Chromium browser (Brave, Kiwi..) on Android

When I click "add to home screen" from the Brave/Chrome menu, on some sites the icon that is added does not open website but instead opens a custom app created for the website (so called "PWA").

I want to create a simple website link that opens the website in a browser (so I can use search / see the url from the address bar and so on).

How can I do that with Brave or Chrome?

Comment: Hi, I believe this is a duplicate of [Chrome and Firefox cannot add specific URL to home screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225002/44325) due to the PWA, and thus I voted to close this as a dupe of that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After tedious search I was finally able to do it.

Simply put - with Brave/Chrome it seems that it is not possible to add a non-PWA shortcut when PWA-version is defined at the web pages web manifest.

HOWEVER there are separate apps on the app store (I don't link to any specific one here but search for example "create shortcut launcher") that allow you to create "custom" shortcuts. With these apps you can create a simple URL shortcut and define which browser is used to open it.

This solves my problem and this question.

To get the corect icon you have to separately download and set the icon which is quite tedious so if anyone solves how to do this with chrome/chromium then please respond and I will change the accepted answer.

Comment: I share your frustration in wanting to just add links to web sites on the new tab page in Brave/Chrome. Would you mind listing which Extension worked well for you? I searched as you suggested and found "G App Installer" however it seems geared to Google Apps.

Comment: I think the one I was using has been renamed - I don't want to advertise specific apps but the one I'm currently using seems to be "Shortcut maker" by "android_rk".

Comment: Thanks for the name of the extension. I also found good luck with an extension named "Humble New Tab Page". Works well for me with Brave (Apple Native) on MacOS.

Comment: I used Http Shortcuts (found on F-Droid).  Then, got the icon off of icons8.com.
With Http Shortcuts, you can just click on the icon and replace it with an image you saved from icons8.com.

Answer (score -1):

One thing you can do is set your homepage. Go to Settings on Chrome. Tap on Homepage. There will be two options, one is called Chrom'e Homepage and the other option is a text box for URLs. You can put HTML content in there for example the following line will create a page with Google as hyperlink. You can create a whole pretty dashboard using this method.

```
 data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></head><body><a href='https://google.com'>Google</a></body></html>
```

The other option is to just bookmark the websites you visit. Then when you start searching in the address bar Chrome will show links from bookmarks. Doesn't always work though.

Comment: Of course I can do this inside the chrome but that is not what the question is about - I want the links to my main launcher page as direct links. I already have some 10 websites that I have on the homepage (with firefox) but I would like to use chrome-based browser like Brave instead.